# Wie soll ich 'full of mistakes' auf Deutsch sagen?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, phrase

Wie soll man *'full of mistakes'* auf Deutsch sagen?

Better be translated into an adjective.

Comment: For a better translation you should [edit] your question and show the context, e.g. an example sentence you want to translate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"**full of mistakes**" can be translated as "**voller Fehler**" or "voll von Fehlern" or "voll mit Fehlern".

If you want a single word you could use **fehlerstrotzend** in an attributive context, e.g. "*ein fehlerstrotzender Text*". I, personally, would **not** use it not in a predicative way like "*Der Text ist fehlerstrotzend.*" In this case I would prefer "*Der Text strotzt vor Fehlern.*" or "*Der Text ist voller Fehler.*" But I have found examples of this usdage as well.

According to dlatikay's comment, the term "ein fehlerstrotzender Text" may be wrong and should be "ein vor Fehlern strotzender Text". In general, "fehlerstrotzend" or the verb "strotzen" is not widely used. In a web search, the first page of results leads do dictionary sites.

Comment: Thank you so much! It should be 'full of mistakes' in Englisch. I made a mistake.

Comment: @wwxq Please, edit your question and fix the mistake, then I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reminding.

Comment: "ein fehlerstrotzender Text" is not something we would write or say. it would have to be an unwieldy "ein vor Fehlern strotzender Text" then.